# Optimising a NBT parser that's only searching for a fraction of data in Python

Tags: python

The nbt file is created by the [schematica mod](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/schematica) for Mincraft.

With `content.find(f'\xYY\xZZ..')` and `content = content[lower:upper]` I was able to slice the data to the most important part: The blockdata which has the following form when translated (my data is NOT translated!):

```
TAG_List("blocks (Compound)"): (xdim*ydim*zdim) entries of type TAG_Compound
{
  TAG_Compound:
  {
    TAG_List("pos (Int)"): 3 entries of type TAG_Int
    {
      TAG_Int: X
      TAG_Int: Y
      TAG_Int: Z
    }
    TAG_Int("state"): S
  }
  //...
  TAG_Compound:
  {
    TAG_Compound("nbt"):
    {
      //Some uninteresting stuff
    }
    TAG_List("pos (Int)"): 3 entries of type TAG_Int
    {
      TAG_Int: X
      TAG_Int: Y
      TAG_Int: Z
    }
    TAG_Int("state"): S
  }
}
```

My goal is to extract all "state" information of the **raw** byte data as fast as possible while ignoring all "pos" and "nbt" data.
Since not every "block"-Compound has a "nbt"-Subcompound, I can't just save every Xth byte, since the length of each "block"-Compound is unknown.

So my current solution is to search for the keyword "state" (`data.find(b'\x73\x74\x61\x74\x65')`), save the following 4 bytes, cut of the word "state" from the data (`data = data[index+4:]`) and iterate.

And I'm by no means an expert, but I feel like there has to be a better way.

To give you a better idea of the data I'm dealing with:

```
b'\t\x00\x06blocks\n\x00\x00\x00\x08\t\x00\x03pos\x03\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x05state\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x03pos\x03\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x05state\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\t\x00\x03pos\x03\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x05state\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\t\x00\x03pos\x03\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x05state\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\n\x00\x03nbt\t\x00\x05Items\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x02id\x00\x0fminecraft:chest\x08\x00\x04Lock\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x03pos\x03\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x03\x00\x05state\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\t\x00\x03pos\x03\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x03\x00\x05state\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\t\x00\x03pos\x03\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x03\x00\x05state\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\t\x00\x03pos\x03\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x03\x00\x05state\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00'
```

(I want the 4 bytes after each "state")

//Edit: I just realized slicing takes a lot of time, so if I just searched for all occurences, I'd be a lot faster.
But I still hope there's a better way